# How to solve this invalid select list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Can anyone have any suggestions on what I'm missing on my query.

I'm having error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Column
> 'Cars.dbo.tblTranslateTable.IDEvent' is invalid in the select list
> because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
> GROUP BY clause.

I wanted to select the count of rows from the translate table, idevent and the date referencing from another table.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) Entries, T.auctionevent,TT.auctiondate 
FROM iDP.dbo.tblTranslateTable T 
INNER JOIN iDx.dbo.tblAuctionEvent TT ON T.AuctionEvent = TT.AuctionEvent
GROUP BY T.auctionevent
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if the column is from another table, if we have a grouping function, we have to mention it in the group by clause.

Comment: Thank you, amir m , I did not know we can add multiple columns after the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) Entries, T.auctionevent,TT.auctiondate 
FROM iDP.dbo.tblTranslateTable T 
INNER JOIN iDx.dbo.tblAuctionEvent TT ON T.AuctionEvent = TT.AuctionEvent 
GROUP BY T.auctionevent ,TT.auctiondate
```